# Getting popup to work on photogallery using javascript function to activate lightbox

Tags: javascript, css

I can't seem to get my photo gallery to work properly when clicking on it. I am trying to use a java function to make a lightbox type affect.

Here is my code:

```
<div style="max-width: 888px; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;" id="thumbnails">
$images_dir = 'images/med/full/';
$thumbs_dir = 'images/med/thumb/';
$thumbs_width = 300;
$thumbs_height = 300;
$images_per_row = 3;

/** generate photo gallery **/
$image_files = get_files($images_dir);
if(count($image_files)) {
$index = 0;
foreach($image_files as $index=>$file) {
$index++;
$thumbnail_image = $thumbs_dir.$file;
if(!file_exists($thumbnail_image)) {
    $extension = get_file_extension($thumbnail_image);
    if($extension) {
        make_thumb  ($images_dir.$file,$thumbnail_image,$thumbs_width,$thumbs_height);
    }
}
echo '<a href="',$images_dir.$file,'" class="photo-link smoothbox" rel="gallery"><img src="',$thumbnail_image,'" /></a>';
if($index % $images_per_row == 0) { echo '<div class="clear"></div>'; }
}
echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
}
else {
echo '<p>There are no images in this gallery.</p>';
}

?>
</div>
```

I am using Smoothbox, but I wasn't able to get it to work. I was hoping I could write a smaller script instead of using the one from the link above.

I've researched creating a simple lightbox such as this one [here](https://davidwalsh.name/generate-photo-gallery), but I'm not sure how to integrate it with my code above.

Here is the link to the website with my photos I want this to work on: http://davishosting.net/ginger/mediterranean

I would like the photo to enlarge and center, with a semi transparent background over everything behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reviewing your code, it looks like your not making any calls to Java.

When linking a js file, you need to add a script element to tell Java an element is being activated.

Try placing the following inbetween your head tags or under the closing tag for your thumbnails div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#thumbnails a').lightbox();
});
</script>
```

I've used smooth box and that code worked fine for me.

Comment: So I have to link the javascript file, but also add a script calling out the function? I am trying this now.

Comment: Yes. I'd suggest reading a turtorial of JavaScript at http://www.w3schools.com/js/